# Quantized tflite model is throwing exception "The load task failed" when run in android app using Firebase ML-Kit

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

When I use quantized tflite model in my android app using ML Kit I get exception "Model Failure:The load task failed". If I use same model that has not been quantized, everything works fine.
I use python to convert frozen model to tflite model.

If I set converter.post_training_quantize = False, model works fine in the android app, but with it being True it does not. Please help why this is happening and what am I missing??
Just for more information its a simple model consists of two convolutional2d layers and fully connected dense layer with binary crossentropy output. Thank you very much.

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(graph_file, inputs, outputs)
converter.post_training_quantize = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(file_path, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: Could you give more details? (which Firebase API are you using? How do you call it?)

Comment: Just like the guide in Firebase ML Kit Docs suggests:

Comment: FirebaseLocalModelSource localSource =
        new FirebaseLocalModelSource.Builder("my_local_model")  // Assign a name to this model
                .setAssetFilePath("my_model.tflite")
                .build();
FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().registerLocalModelSource(localSource);

Comment: FirebaseModelOptions options = new FirebaseModelOptions.Builder()
        .setCloudModelName("my_cloud_model")
        .setLocalModelName("my_local_model")
        .build();
FirebaseModelInterpreter firebaseInterpreter =
        FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options);

Comment: FirebaseModelInputs inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
        .add(input)  // add() as many input arrays as your model requires
        .build();
firebaseInterpreter.run(inputs, inputOutputOptions)